# Is there a way to make a screen larger in Windows 10 display settings?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

I have 4 monitors connected to a PC; 3 in a row and one centered above that row. The monitor on top is larger than the 3 in the row below so it overlaps the 2 side screens. Currently, I can only enter the top monitor with my mouse by going up from the center monitor but I'm wondering if it is possible to make it so I can enter the top monitor from the center monitor and half of the side monitors?

Here is a crude screen capture to help try and explain:

[image]

Comment: This http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/ may help (has a free trial). I've not tried this tool, do so at your own risk! Same wtih http://www.displayfusion.com/